# mmap() after deleting the file

Tags: c++

I was told, that mmap() might be in trouble, if someone deletes the original file. I was wondering if that really happens. So i created some little test-program. I am using linux.

```
#include <iostream>

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int, char**)
{
    char const * const fileName = "/tmp/demo-file.dat";
    size_t size;

    {
        struct stat st;
        stat(fileName, &st);
        size = st.st_size;
    }

    int fd = open(fileName, O_RDWR);
    if (fd == -1)
    {
        std::cout << "open() failed, errno = " << errno << ":" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
        return (-1);
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "open() done (ok)" << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 20; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << "file open()'ed, wait #" << i << " seconds before mmap()" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    void *data = mmap((void*)0L, size, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd, (off_t)0);
    if (data == (void*)-1)
    {
        std::cout << "mmap() failed, errno = " << errno << ":" << strerror(errno) << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "mmap() done (ok)" << std::endl;
    }

    for (int i = 20; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << "going to close() socket in #" << i << " seconds" << std::endl;
        sleep (1);
    }

    close(fd);

    for (int i = 30; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << "going to umap() files in #" << i << " seconds (still accessing the data)" << std::endl;
        for (unsigned int x = 0; x < size; ++x)
        {
            char cp = *(char*) (data + x);
            (void) cp;
        }
        sleep(1);
    }

    munmap(data, size);

    for (int i = 30; i > 0; --i)
    {
        std::cout << "going to terminate #" << i << " seconds" << std::endl;
        sleep(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Whenever i delete the file - after the open() operation - it doesn't have negative impact to then mmap(). I can still acess the data in the test program.
When i delete the file right after close(), but before mmap(), it works. I can also still see the old file in the /proc/[pid]/fd/ area:

```
lrwx------ 1 frank frank 64 Mär 22 20:28 3 -> /tmp/demo-file.dat (deleted)
```

The rest of the program works.

Even when i delete the file **after** the close() it still succeeds to access the mmap() data.
However in both cases, **after** the close() i cannot see the

```
lrwx------ 1 frank frank 64 Mär 22 20:28 3 -> /tmp/demo-file.dat (deleted)
```

anymore. (btw: where is then noted, that this file "still exists somehow"?)

So is it the opposite, that it is guaranteed, that mmap() will still be able to operate on the data, even if the file was manually deleted (in a shell or by some other process)?

Comment: The file will still have an active inode. inodes are kept alive through reference counting. Your open file handle is a reference.

Comment: When a file is opened, the process receives a descriptor or file stream pointing to the inode of the file. Deleting the file only removes the file entry in the directory. The inodes are not returned to the filesystem until the last reference is closed.

Comment: A filename in a directory is not the file. Unix is not Windows.

Comment: I know for file descriptors and accordingly showing up in /proc/[pid]/fd/.... How is this reference counting modelled for mmap()?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what's happening.

The first thing to check is

```
$ls -i /tmp/demo-file.dat
65 /tmp/demo-file.dat
```

Note the inode number of the file is 65.

On starting the program, here's what it has in its `lsof` output (apart from other entries not relevant to the current discourse)

```
a.out   29271 zoso    3u   REG   0,21        5       65 /tmp/demo-file.dat
```

This is a result of the `open()` that's been done. Note that the inode number is the same as the other file. The `open()` has increased the ref count on the same inode. Also, note that `REG` indicates a regular file.

Now if the file is deleted (using `rm` etc.), here's what the `lsof` looks like

```
a.out   29271 zoso    3u   REG   0,21        5       65 /tmp/demo-file.dat (deleted)
```

This is expected since the file that was opened has been deleted but the handle that to its inode still is open in the process.

Moving on to the mmap, and here's the `lsof` output

```
a.out   29271 zoso  DEL    REG   0,21                65 /tmp/demo-file.dat
a.out   29271 zoso    3u   REG   0,21        5       65 /tmp/demo-file.dat (deleted)
```

Now there's another new entry but note that this is of type `DEL` which indicates (lifting from [lsof](https://linux.die.net/man/8/lsof) man page):

> ''DEL'' for a Linux map file that has been deleted;

Since `lsof` can't stat the original file anymore, it puts this mapping as `DEL` with no size of course, yet note that the inode number still remains the same i.e 65.

Now after `close()` has been called on the fd here's what `lsof` shows

```
a.out   29271 zoso  DEL    REG   0,21                65 /tmp/demo-file.dat
```

Note that the `(deleted)` entry is gone since that fd to a `REG` file has been closed and now only the mmap'd memory remains.

After `munmap()` this entry too is gone (no more references to `/tmp/demo-file.dat` and finally the program ends.